# (Mac) download page and subpages using wget for offline viewing using localhost

Tags: macos, wget, localhost

I have http://some/page and I want to download the page itself and all other pages under it, N levels deep.

So if I set N to e.g. 2, I would be downloading:

```
http://some/page,
http://some/page/a,
http://some/page/a/1,
http://some/page/a/2,
....
..
http://some/page/b,
http://some/page/b/1,
http://some/page/b/2,
....
..
etc.
```

I then want to be able to browse the "website" I've downloaded, but I want to be able to move around the website-folder in my HD, without having to worry about local relative links breaking. That's why I'm mentioning localhost in the title, maybe it's not needed I don't know.

Is there some wget command I can use for this or some software with a GUI ?

I don't know much about wget (nor am I very familiar with the terminal) and I couldn't find any human-friendly docs about it so having the command itself with some explanation about its flags would help a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After all I found and am using this:

```
wget -r --level 2 --random-wait --no-clobber --page-requisites --e robots=off --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent http://some/page
```

Comment: +1 for a useful wget example, but -1 for not answering your own question (which I don't think is possible in wget).  You asked to download "everything under some/page", but your answer only downloads things that are *linked* directly on some page or linked on those links.  If there is no link to, say, `http://some/page/b/1` on any of those pages, this command will not download it.

Answer (score 0):

I use both curl and wget for scripts but for a one-off download of a site I find Sitesucker very easy to use:

http://ricks-apps.com/osx/sitesucker/index.html